# Cascading parameters and forward dependencies

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008 R2.

Given 2 multivalued parameters @City and @State, I have created dropdown lists for both. I can set @City to n-values, and @State will filter itself so that it only shows States associated to those City names.

Example: Check Springfield, and all states that have a city named Springfield show up.

Simultaneously, I want the option to set the @State values and have @City show only cities associated with those states. Basically have all dropdown lists update based on the last change made. If I write a simple WHERE clause in each dataset, I will get forward dependency errors since they will just keep looping each other.

What's the best approach to do this?

Comment: 1. Both lists are *check* lists, is that right? 2. Are you asking about a SQL solution or an SSRS solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want cannot be done in SSRS AFAIK, the tool's just not very good at this type of faceted search.

Alternatives and workarounds may include:

- A text parameter `@Search` followed by `@City` and `@State`, both filtered on the search parameter.
- Use a ReportViewer in your app and build your own custom search control to work out your requirement.
- (Hack / ugly) use four parameters, two pairs, with in each pair the other parameter first.

Answer (score 2):

I just found it somewhere else - you just need to change parameter order in the parameter's node!!!! State should be over the City and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can use to solve this issue, there's an example here which is used to force a child parameter to refresh when the selection of the parent changes, but I think you could extend it to work both ways:

http://www.bp-msbi.com/2011/04/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/